# Working with setters and getters

Tags: javascript

I'm really trying to break down setters and getters to understand them.
I think that a setter can be used if there is a condition:

```js
var Temperature = {}
Temperature.closure = null
var init = {}
init.get = function() {
 return this.closure
}
Object.defineProperty(Temperature, "b", init)
init = {}
init.set = function(arg) {
 if (arg > -459.67) { // sanity check to make sure it's above 0 degrees Kelvin
  this.closure = arg
 }
}
Object.defineProperty(Temperature, "c", init)

console.log(Temperature.b); // null
Temperature.c = 32;
console.log(Temperature.b); // 32
Temperature.c = -5000
console.log(Temperature.b); // still 32
```

What I'd like to do is get rid of the .b and the .c so that I can just say

```
Temperature = 32
```

or

```
console.log(Temperature)
```

Comment: You would like `Temperature = 32` to do what exactly?

Comment: I wonder if both of your properties are *sharing* the same `init` object, that may be an issue here.  When using `defineProperty`, you can (and should) pass it an object literal directly: `Object.defineProperty(Temperature, "b", { get: function(){} })`

Comment: @RocketHazmat They aren't sharing the same object.

Comment: Assign the value of 32 to the object "Temperature"

Comment: Well if `Temperature` was a property of another object you could do it, i.e. `c.Temperature = 32` if c has defined getters/setters for `Temperature`. Other than that, a variable itself is not an object, you cannot define getters/setters on a variable (what would you be declaring them on?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
 get temperature() {
  return this.value 
 }
 ,set temperature(arg) {
  if (arg > -459.67) {
   this.value = arg
  }
 }
}
obj.value = null

console.log(obj.temperature) // null
obj.temperature = Math.PI
console.log(obj.temperature) // 3.141592653589793
obj.temperature = -5000
console.log(obj.temperature) // 3.141592653589793
```

Comment: The thing that you were confused about was in [their example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters), they used b and c when they should have used the same name for both.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr:** you can't.

To use setters and getters you need to have a property of something. If you use a locally scoped variable with `var`, `let` or `const` you won't be able to attach (what amounts to) a listener for overwriting the variable, because the variable itself is being completely replaced with a new reference.

---

As an alternative to a local variable:

If you're using `Temperature` in the context of an object, you could choose to use a property of that object via `this.temperature` instead of a locally scoped variable.

---

If you insist on using a local variable, you could consider building a more complex `Temperature` object, which has properties for setting a value, but also has a `valueOf` method for conversion to a numeric:

```
function Temperature(kelvin) {
  this._internalValue = kelvin || 0;
}

Temperature.prototype = {
  get kelvin() {...}
  set kelvin(val) {...}
  get celsius() {...}
  set celsius(val) {...}
  get farenheit() {...}
  set farenheit(val) {...}
  valueOf: function () {
    return this._internalValue;
  }
}
```

You would still need to use a property for assignment:

```
var temperature = new Temperature();
temperature.celsius = 0;
```

but you could then get the numeric value directly from the object:

```
console.log(+temperature);
//          ^ cast to a Number
```